# Execution after waiting for events of multiple threads while keeping started processes running

Tags: java, multithreading

Basically I'm starting multiple threads which again start a long running process which should be monitored. In the example the "long" running processes are simple ping calls. An IpListener has the responsibility to trigger events, when the process ends or fails.

Now comes the interesting part: Everytime when an ip is found in the console output the onIpFound method is triggered. What I want to do is to wait till all threads have found an IP for the first time and then continue with the execution of the main method. However the started processes should continue to run and eventually should trigger the aforementioned onProcessEnd and onProcessFailure events. Do you have any hints to implement this behavior (in a sound manner)?

Here are the parts of the small example application to give you a better understanding:

ReaderTest.java

```
package com.test;
public class ReaderTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        IpReader ipReader = new IpReader("stackoverflow.com");
        ipReader.setListener(new SimpleIpListener());
        new Thread(ipReader).start();

        IpReader ipReader2 = new IpReader("stackexchange.com");
        ipReader2.setListener(new SimpleIpListener());
        new Thread(ipReader2).start();

        // TODO: start next step as soon as both ips are known
    }
}
```

IpReader.java

```
package com.test;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class IpReader implements Runnable {

    private IpListener ipListener = null;
    private String hostName;

    public IpReader(String hostName) {
        this.hostName = hostName;
    }

    public interface IpListener {
        public void onIpFound(String ip);

        public void onProcessEnd(String string);

        public void onProcessFailure(String string);
    }

    public void setListener(IpListener ipListener) {
        this.ipListener = ipListener;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder().command("cmd", "/c", "ping", "-n", "10", hostName);
        pb.redirectErrorStream(true);

        Process process = null;
        try {
            try {
                process = pb.start();

                String line = null;
                // print stream
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {

                    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?:[0-9]{1,3}\\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}");
                    Matcher m = p.matcher(line);

                    if (m.find()) {
                        // IPv4 found
                        if (ipListener != null) {
                            ipListener.onIpFound(m.group(0));
                        }
                    }
                }

                process.waitFor();
                if (ipListener != null)
                    ipListener.onProcessEnd("Process END");
            } finally {
                if (process != null)
                    process.destroy();
            }

        } catch (InterruptedException | IOException e) {
            if (ipListener != null)
                ipListener.onProcessFailure("Process failure");
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

SimpleIpListener.java

```
package com.test;
import com.test.IpReader.IpListener;

public class SimpleIpListener implements IpListener {

    private boolean ipFound = false;

    @Override
    public void onIpFound(String ip) {
        if (!ipFound)
            System.out.println("IP " + ip + " found.");
        ipFound = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessEnd(String string) {
        System.out.println("Process ended.");
    }

    @Override
    public void onProcessFailure(String string) {
        System.out.println("Process failure");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of doing this is to introduce an object shared between the IpReader (or your listener) threads that they can all update when they have found an ip.

For example introduce this simple class:

```
class WaitTask {
    private int numberRead;

    public int getNumberRead(){
        return numberRead;
    } 

    public void increment(){
        numberRead++;
    }
}
```

Now in your main method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // create an instance of that class, which keeps track of how many threads found an ip
    final WaitTask waitTask = new WaitTask();
    // create an int to know how many we are expecting
    final int totalThreadsRunning = 2;

    IpReader ipReader = new IpReader("stackoverflow.com");
    ipReader.setListener(new SimpleIpListener());

    // pass our object to the thread
    ipReader.setWaitTask(waitTask);
    new Thread(ipReader).start();

    IpReader ipReader2 = new IpReader("stackexchange.com");
    ipReader2.setListener(new SimpleIpListener());

    // pass our object to the thread
    ipReader2.setWaitTask(waitTask);
    new Thread(ipReader2).start();

    // Now wait until the wait task object is safe to be accessed

    synchronized(waitTask){

        // once we know it's safe let's check if we read as many responses as required

        while(waitTask.getNumberRead() < totalThreadsRunning )
        {
            // instead of looping forever wait for a thread to notify that 
            // the wait task number read was changed

            waitTask.wait();
            // the wait blocks execution and waits until waitTask was             
            // changed, after that the while loop condition gets evaluated
            // once we read as many as required we exit the loop
        }
    }

    // when we reach here all threads have finished so do anything you want
}
```

And in your IpThread add:

```
private WaitTask waitTask;

public void setWaitTask(WaitTask task){
    this.waitTask = task;
}

[...]

// IPv4 found
    if (ipListener != null) {
        ipListener.onIpFound(m.group(0));
        // wait again until the wait task is safe to be accesed
        synchronized(waitTask){
            // increment it's value
            waitTask.increment();
            // notify that we changed the value
            waitTask.notify();
        }

    }
[...]
```

Answer (score 0):

Use "atomic variables" to store the ip addresses. These can be set by the ping threads and checked by the main thread. In your main thread halt on a "condition variable". When the ping threads receive an ip address, they will wake up the main thread. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Condition.html
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicReference.html

What this will do is, you set up a variable that the ping thread can post data, and the main thread can also read. Additionally the main thread will halt on the condition variable(and consume no processor time) but wake up when a new ip is found. Then it will check if both ip references are filled.

Define these globally:

```
AtomicReference ip1 = new AtomicReference(new String(""));
AtomicReference ip2 = new AtomicReference(new String(""));
final Lock lock = new ReentrantLock();
final Condition wakeup  = lock.newCondition();
```

Then in main thread

```
while(ip1.get().length == 0 && ip2.get().length == 0)
{
wakeup.await();
}
```

In IpReader definition:

```
 private String hostName;
 private AtomicReference ipstring;

public IpReader(String hostName,AtomicReference outputstring) {
    this.hostName = hostName;
    this.ipstring = outputstring;
}
```

Finally

```
@Override
public void onIpFound(String ip, AtomicReference ref) {
    if (!ipFound)
        System.out.println("IP " + ip + " found.");
    ipFound = true;
    ref.set(ip);
    wakeup.signal();
}
```